# C++: Passing object to class constructor, how is it stored?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, reference

Consider the following example of a simple class implementation in C++.

foo.hpp

```
#include <vector>
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<double> X;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(std::vector<double>&);
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
Foo::Foo(std::vector<double>& X):
        X(X)
{}
```

In this case, the vector X is passed by reference to the constructor of the class Foo. I start having doubts, though, on whether the operation X(X) in the implementation makes a copy and pastes it "in" the member X of the class.

Which is it?

Comment: It calls copy constructor of vector. (you have only one copy).

Comment: First, do you expect the caller to hold onto their version of the vector?  If not, then create a move constructor, `Foo(std::vector<double>&& X)` and `std::move()` into the member `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the data member `X` will be copy-initialized from the constructor parameter `X`.

If you declare the data member `X` as reference, then no copy operation happens. E.g.

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<double>& X;
public:
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(std::vector<double>&);
};

Foo::Foo(std::vector<double>& X):
        X(X)
{}
```

Then

```
std::vector<double> v;
Foo f(v); // no copies; f.X refers to v
```

Comment: Great, that’s what I’m looking for. Thanks

Comment: @G.Gare Pay attention to the lifetime, if the referenced object is destroyed the reference becomes dangling. And you might need to implement assignment operator by yourself.

Comment: Stupid question: in your code what happens to the vector ```v``` if the class instance ```f``` is destroyed?

Comment: @G.Gare: nothing.  Be wary: raw references and raw pointers are considered 'non-owning'.  Here's a lead on this: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-ref

So it's up to _you_ to make sure that `v` stays alive while `f` is using it, and to clean it up (which will happen automatically in this case: stack variable)

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured.  The member's type is `vector<double>`, so the compiler will look for a constructor overload in the `vector<double>` class that matches the provided argument type (`vector<double>&`).

The best match it will find is the `const vector<double>&` overload - the copy constructor.

Comment: So it will make a copy of X? That’s something I want to avoid

Comment: @G.Gare what do you want if not a copy?

Comment: A reference. The vector X is huge in my application, so better not copying it around the code

Comment: Then you should declare the member as a reference (or a pointer).  The member will be initialized with the address-of the reference argument.

Comment: @G.Gare -- What do you consider a huge amount of data?  A vector stores its data in contiguous memory, not fragmented all over the heap like `std::list` or even an associative container such as `std::set` or `std::map`.  So maybe your concerns shouldn't be concerns?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to this, you can create a constructor with an rvalue reference for the class:

```
#include <vector>
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<double> X;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(const std::vector<double>&);
    Foo(std::vector<double>&&);
};
```

Then the constructor would be implemented like this:

```
Foo::Foo(std::vector<double>&& X_) : X(std::move(X_)) {}
```

No copy is done when this constructor is invoked.

Comment: Did you know the "Rule of 5/7/0"?  How should that apply to the proposed class?

Comment: The constructor with the r-value reference is not `Foo(Foo&&)`.  So it's not really a move constructor, but one that takes an r-value reference.  Should reword the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, X (the member of the Foo class) is `copy-constructed`. One solution to prevent the copy would be defining X as an `lvalue reference` in the Foo class, though it is not a general solution for all cases, and it can be dangerous (result in a dangling reference) if the scope of the original X is finished when Foo is still alive! All in all, you have one of the below options depending on your application

1. Using `lvalue reference` to X, if the scope of each possible Foo object is lower than the passed object (X):

   foo.hpp

   ```
   #include <vector>
   class Foo {
   private:
       std::vector<double> &X;
   public:
       Foo() = default;
       ~Foo() = default;
       Foo(std::vector<double>&);
   };
   ```

   foo.cpp

   ```
   #include "Foo.hpp"
   Foo::Foo(std::vector<double>& X):
           X(X) // keep the lvalue refrence to the passed Object
   {}
   ```

Then

```
std::vector<double> v;
Foo f(v); // no copies; f.X refers to v
// Foo function calls including f.X should be finished before destruction of the v Object
```

2. Cast X to an `rvalue reference` (std::move) and move it to the member X of Foo class, if X contents are not supposed to be usable through the passed Object name after the Foo constructor call:

   foo.hpp

   ```
    #include <vector>
    class Foo {
    private:
        std::vector<double> X;
    public:
        Foo() = default;
        ~Foo() = default;
        Foo(std::vector<double>&&);
    };
   ```

   foo.cpp

   ```
    #include "Foo.hpp"
    Foo::Foo(std::vector<double>&& X):
            X(std::move(X)) // move constructor of std::vector<double> is called in this line
    {}
   ```

Then

```
std::vector<double> v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; 
Foo f(std::move(v)); // no copies; f.X use resource of v, but v is empty now
// v is empty now
```

3. The last method is exactly the same as your implementation. In this case:
   foo.hpp

   ```
    #include <vector>
    class Foo {
    private:
        std::vector<double> X;
    public:
        Foo() = default;
        ~Foo() = default;
        Foo(const std::vector<double>&);
    };
   ```

   foo.cpp

   ```
    #include "Foo.hpp"
    Foo::Foo(const std::vector<double>& X): // using const is better! in this case
            X(X) // copy constructor of std::vector<double> is called in this line
    {}
   ```

Then

```
std::vector<double> v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
Foo f(v); // do copies; f.X copy the resource of v, and v is still valid
```

Having said that, all of these methods have their own applications depending on the situation. For the sake of clarity, just simply apply this prioritizing rule:
1- pass by `rvalue reference`, which results in `move constructor` for the member. (e.g., when you want to pass an object to the std::thread constructor, and so the ownership, meaning the resources, and so resources lifetime!).
2- pass the `lvalue reference` and keep it, when the passed object lifetime (v in these examples) is greater than the referring one.
3- pass `const lvalue reference` and let the `copy constructor` be called (`copy constructor` of `std::vector` in these examples), when the last choices are not applicable, either due to the further use of the passed object or due to the `lifetime` of the passed Object.